# Get image paths from MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database which contains multiple images (paths) under separate columns i.e. id, image1, image2, image3 and so on.

I am using the code below to retrieve the images based on the id in the URL and display them in a slider on the php page.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE ` id`='" . $id . "'";  
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$image1 = $fetch['image1'];
$image2 = $fetch['image2'];
$image3 = $fetch['image3'];
$image4 = $fetch['image4'];
$image5 = $fetch['image5'];
$image6 = $fetch['image6'];
$image7 = $fetch['image7'];
$image8 = $fetch['image8'];
$image9 = $fetch['image9'];
$image10 = $fetch['image10'];
}
```

And to show the images:

```
echo '<a data-Img='.$image1.' href='.$image1.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$image1.'></a>';
echo '<a data-Img='.$image2.' href='.$image2.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$image2.'></a>';
echo '<a data-Img='.$image3.' href='.$image3.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$image3.'></a>';
echo '<a data-Img='.$image4.' href='.$image4.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$image4.'></a>';
echo '<a data-Img='.$image5.' href='.$image5.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$image5.'></a>';
echo '<a data-Img='.$image6.' href='.$image6.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$image6.'></a>';
echo '<a data-Img='.$image7.' href='.$image7.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$image7.'></a>';
echo '<a data-Img='.$image8.' href='.$image8.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$image8.'></a>';
echo '<a data-Img='.$image9.' href='.$image9.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$image9.'></a>';
echo '<a data-Img='.$image10.' href='.$image10.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$image10.'></a>';
```

This works ok but not all items in the database have 10 images so for items with only, for example 5 images, blank image placeholders are shown? Can this be prevented or will a different method of storing the images be needed?

Comment: What would the expected outcome be? No output at all for missing images? Do you need to keep them in a grid of some sort?

Comment: There should be no output for the missing images

Comment: show your table image value.

Answer (score 1):

According to your db design, you can store the name of the images in an array instead of ten different variables. So if there are only five images in the table row, the array will be filled with only five image names. And at the time of displaying you can use "foreach" loop to extract the image names.

example code :
*for storing images in array*

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE ` id`='" . $id . "'";  
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$image[1] = $fetch['image1'];
$image[2] = $fetch['image2'];
$image[3] = $fetch['image3'];
$image[4] = $fetch['image4'];
$image[5] = $fetch['image5'];
$image[6] = $fetch['image6'];
$image[7] = $fetch['image7'];
$image[8] = $fetch['image8'];
$image[9] = $fetch['image9'];
$image[10] = $fetch['image10'];
}
```

*to display images*

```
foreach($image as $pic) {
echo '<a data-Img='.$pic.' href='.$pic.'>';echo '<img class="Tmb" alt="" src='.$pic.'></a>';
}
```

Hope this will help...

Comment: Thank you, if I change my database design to just two columns, ID & Path, can I still use this code to retrieve and store and display the images? The image paths in the DB are named in accordance with the ID of the row, i.e 200-1.jpg, 200-2.jpg, 200-3.jpg

Comment: Yes you can use array format. In that case try code like this..    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$image_array[] = $fetch['image']; }

Comment: Thanks but this is not displaying any images? There are 5 images in the DB under the column 'image'. All are assigned to ID of 200 which is the ID in the URL of the page. I have used the second piece of code in your original answer along with the $image_array[] = $fetch['image']; query above but nothing displays?

Comment: We have used only the name of the images. There is no path to images. That means the images have to be in the same directory as  the PHP file where you wrote the code to display the images. If you use your previous db design, those piece of code should work fine.  Thank you..

Answer (score -1):

your db structure is partially wrong. If you have more than one images which they related to same id you should store them on different table like

**images_table**

```
img_id | img_path
100    | path1
100    | path2
101    | path3
102    | path3
```

So you will have chance to add 11th or 20th image for your same id. If you have 100 images for same id will you create +90 column for they?

Answer (score -1):

As someone has told you, whenever you have a variable number of colums for a records, it's better to split the table in two, relating each of them by a field (foreign key).

```
+--------+      +---------+
| Table1 |      |  Table2 |
+--------+      +---------+
|   row  |<-----|  idRow  |
+--------+      +---------+
                |  image  |
                +---------+

SELECT t1.row, t2.image FROM table1 t1
                        JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.row = t2.idRow
```

This SQL query should return something like

```
+-------+----------+
| row1  |  image1  |
+-------+----------+
| row1  |  image2  |
+-------+----------+
| row1  |  image3  |
+-------+----------+
| row1  |  image4  |
+-------+----------+
| row1  |  image5  |
+-------+----------+
| row2  |  image1  |
+-------+----------+
| row2  |  image2  |
+-------+----------+
| row2  |  image3  |
+-------+----------+
| row3  |  image1  |
+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Your system display images with separate columns for each image is ineffective.

Not effective at all.

```
    ----- ----- ----------
   | ID | Name | Path     |
    ----- ----- ----------
   | 1  | Home |  1.jpg   |
   | 2  | Logo |  2.jpg   |
   | 3  | .... |  3.jpg   |
    ---- ------ ----------
```

It's faster, efficient, and useful.

I don't understand your problem, you have a specific explanation?